# AngularJS update ng-model if value = true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Hello I'm building an app that overviews data from a database. I have a form which loads that information with ng-model into input fields, The user have the option to change these values.

However I dont want the values on the overview to live update when the user changes the value in input fields. Only once the form has been submitted do I want to see the changes.

I have this HTML on the overview side

```
<dt>COMPANY</dt>
<dd>{{client.company}}</dd>
<dt>NAME</dt>
<dd>{{client.firstname}} {{client.lastname}}</dd>
```

and the form is

```
<p>Company</p><input type="text" name="ciCompany" class="pinfo" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'value = true' }" required ng-model="client[0].company">
<p>First Name</p><input type="text" name="ciFirstName" class="pinfo" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'value = true' }" required ng-model="client[0].firstname">
<p>Last Name</p><input type="text" name="ciLastName" class="pinfo" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'value = true' }" required ng-model="client[0].lastname">
```

I dont know if using ng-model-options is the right approach. But logically this is how I want it to work. But it doesn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angular.copy to do this:

```
$scope.clients = {}; // your array
$scope.clientsCopy = angular.copy($scope.clients);

<dt>COMPANY</dt>
<dd>{{clientsCopy.company}}</dd>
<dt>NAME</dt>
<dd>{{clientsCopy.firstname}} {{clientsCopy.lastname}}</dd>

<form ng-submit="userSubmit()">
  <p>Company</p><input type="text" required ng-model="clients[0].company">
</form>
```

Then you can use the onSubmit to update the new values:

```
$scope.userSubmit = function() {
  $scope.clientsCopy = $scope.clients; 
}
```

**You can also use _.extends or _.merge if you are using underscore or lodash.**

Answer (score 0):

On form submit You have to use angular.copy method to copy your data, like this :

```js
$scope.client = angular.copy(clients[0]);
```

Please refer to this : [reference link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)